# ffmpeg doesn't send data through udp

Tags: ffmpeg, udp

Im using ffmpeg to stream my desktop (the server) to another computer (the client)

**server command:**

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f mpegts udp:1.2.3.4:1234
```

**client command:**

```
ffplay -f mpegts udp://4.3.2.1:1234
```

when I run the server and the client on the same computer (using ip 127.0.0.1) it works and I can see my desktop. but when i try to send it to another computer it fails.

I checked my network traffic, and apparently the server isn't sending any data.

So why is the data not sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server had some sort of port block, I [made an exaption](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100027250) in my firewall to allow communication through this port.